# SAS sql select variable as change name to a date in MonYY7. format

Tags: sql, date, select, sas, rename

I am not sure if it is possible at all, but in case someone knows the answer. I need to select variables and rename them to dates in MonYY7. format. My understanding is that SAS stores dates as numbers, and it is the formats which represent them in the former way. However, would it be possible to somehow rename the variable's name itself according to the format?

Here is the code I have written:

```
%macro try;


%let month_count_back = 12; 
%let today = %sysfunc(today());
%let sysmonth = %sysfunc(month("&sysdate"d));

proc sql;
create table try as
select *,
%do i = -&sysmonth. %to -&month_count_back.-&sysmonth.+1 %by -1;
max(month(FP_NDT) = month(intnx('month',&today.,&i.))) as mn%eval(&month_count_back.+&sysmonth.+&i.)
%if &i. = -&month_count_back.-&sysmonth.+1 %then %goto leave_month;
,
%leave_month:
%end;

from work.test
group by var;
quit;

run;
%mend try;
%try;
run;
```

It returns dummy indicators for each month value of the 'var' variable for the previous year (the intention here is to know which values are null and which are not). However, I would like each dummy variable created be named according to the month and the year it refers to. For example, m12 should be DEC2015, m11 - NOV2015 etc... As a corollary if month_count_back is equal to, say, 36 then m36 should be DEC2015, but M12 should be DEC2013 and M1 should be JAN2013 etc...

Maybe there is way to rename it later in a data step? I have tried to loop through it, but could not control for the changing month_count_back value...

Would appreciate any suggestions, thanks!

Comment: Without data it is difficult to tell what you are trying to do especially running a `do` loop inside of a sql select statement. Also, please indent code for readibility.

Comment: Can you explain the under lying problem?  Perhaps you are making it more complicated by assuming that the solution should use columns with names based on dates.  That sounds more like a report that you would run against your real data.

Comment: Your best bet is to compile your report, create the names and then transpose the data to what you want.

Comment: I would convert to variable type to _Date_ thenextract _month_ and _year_ and concatenate them using `||` to form a character variable. Now you can transpose using `proc transpose`